# Difference between Instruction, operations and micro-operation (uop)

Tags: performance, cpu, counter

I am trying to understand the intricate terms related to performance of processors.

Computer performance is measured in `FLOPS`, which is short for *FLOPs per Second*. `FLOPs` itself stands for *Floating-point Operations*.

Now, why is floating-point operations considered for the performance of a computer. What about integer operations? Is there any source online (official citation) that would explain this trend? Google did not give me anything with my searching.

Now, what exactly does operation in FLOP mean? Does that mean a mathematical operation like `MUL`, `ADD`, `DIV` etc?

In this case, what would be an *instruction*? If an *instruction* is something like `ADDPD`, `ADDSD` etc, as I can see here (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28388/epmpv.html), then one instruction can lead to many internal operations. Would that be *micro-operations* or *uops*?

I did not find the explanation for micro-operation on Wikipedia helpful. Whoever explains this clearly here will probably have to improve the Wikipedia article as well :)

According to the Hennessy/Patterson book on Computer Architecture (5th edition, page 233), the *ARM Cortex-A8 (RISC)* is able to execute two instructions per clock. Does that mean that the processor can perform, for example an `ADDPD` and an `ADDSD` (total=2 Instructions) in one cycle?

This source (http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/high-performance-computing/w/wiki/2329) states the following:

> Most microprocessors today can do four (4) FLOPs per clock cycle, that
>   is, 4 FLOPs per Hz.

I believe the author is wrong. He probably implied 4 *Instructions per cycles*, limiting himself to CISC-based (Intel for example) processors. That is because some instructions like FMA on Haswell can boost performance whereby the processor can process more operations per cycle. In other words, 1 `FMA` *instruction* translates to a couple of *operations*. Am I right?

IPC stands for Instruction per Cycle. What instructions are referred here? The instructions retired by the processor? With a hardware counter, I can count the number of CPU cycles and the number of `INST_RETIRED.ANY`. Would that be the right way to calculate IPC?

Thank you very much for any answers and comments. Hopefully my question will help many other confused souls :)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Can you please be more specific on your question? Also you have asked more than 1 question here and therefore it is difficult to answer this. Please see [the help](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) of this site.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between an ADD operation dealing with an integer and an ADD operation dealing with a floating point?  To understand any answer to this question you would need to understand the difference.

Comment: @Ramhound, the ADDs would be different as two different ALUs would compute them. On Sandy Bridge/Ivy Bridge for instance, there are two separate ALUs under port 0 that do these computations. However, when we talk about performance, we talk about FLOPS. Integer ops are not taken into consideration. So this is confusing. I think that all the sub-questions relate to the bigger question which deals about the difference between the three terms. I will re-formulate the whole question so that I can get better answers and less downvotes :)

Comment: @shailenTJ - I am confused by the question to be honest.  You undersand the difference how an integer and a floating point are handled.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, why is floating-point operations considered for the performance of a computer. What about integer operations?

Floating-point operations is just one of several metrics that have been used over the years to benchmark computer performance.  Measuring FP operations is considered to be more applicable for some real-world applications (such as weather simulations) than integer operations. If you were evaluating computers for a database application, you would probably ignore the FLOPS specifications, and focus on IPS (instructions per second) and I/O performance.

> Now, what exactly does operation in FLOP mean? Does that mean a mathematical operation like MUL, ADD, DIV etc?

The "operation" is the execution of the "instruction", which is a machine code (i.e. a binary value), or one calculation by the FPU, Floating Point Unit.  The (older) FPU typically runs asynchronously with the CPU and ALU, in order to not hinder program execution that is not dependent on the FP result.

Note that a computer (circa 1980) that did not have a FPU could be upgraded with a FPU peripheral.  The FP library of software routines that implemented fundamental FP operations (add, subtract, multiply, divide, square root etc.) would be replaced with a library that invoked I/O instructions to access the FPU peripheral.  An interrupt from the FPU would notify the CPU that the FP operation was complete.

Early PCs were of similar construction.  The original IBM PC used the Intel 8088
microprocessor which did not have HW FP capability.  But an 8087 math co-processor could be installed, so that the FP instructions could be performed by hardware instead of being redirected to software routines.  Eventually Intel integrated the math co-processor in the CPU package for the i486

> In this case, what would be an instruction?

"Instruction" should not be an ambiguous entity. It's one machine code or one mnemomic of the processor.

> then one instruction can lead to many internal operations. Would that be micro-operations or uops?

Apparently you are referring to microprogramming.
(There used to be a computer company that took *micro*programming one iteration lower: to the *nano*programming level.  The products were for CPU emulation.)
Microprogramming is not really relevant to application program performance.  That is, you typically cannot rewrite/improve the microprogramming as you could on a nanoprogram processor.

> Does that mean that the processor can perform, for example an ADDPD and an ADDSD (total=2 Instructions) in one cycle?

Sort of.  Performing more than one instruction per clock cycle requires a *pipeline* of  "execution units".  Think of a (vehicle) manufacturing assembly line.  At each station a specific task is performed.  At the end of the assembly line (pipeline), only one vehicle (instruction) is completed at a time.  The concurrency is staggered, rather than synchronized.

> What instructions are referred here?

Each instruction is a machine code.

> In other words, 1 FMA instruction translates to a couple of operations. Am I right?

No, one instruction correlates to one operation.